# How can I create many tables of the main one and store them?

Tags: matlab

```
my_table = readtable('some.csv')

'L1'    'B'
'L2'    'B'
'L3'    'A'
'L4'    'C'
'L5'    'B'
'L6'    'C'
'L7'    'C'
'L8'    'A'
```

In the second column there are different values, B, A, and C. I want to create smaller tables from this one, depending on the value in the right, so the expected outcome would be:

```
'L1'    'B'
'L2'    'B'
'L5'    'B'
```

and

```
'L3'    'A'
'L8'    'A'
```

and

```
'L4'    'C'
'L6'    'C'
'L7'    'C'
```

each of them stored in a different variable for later use.

Comment: "depending on the value in the left" do you mean depending on the values in the second column, which is on the *right*?

Comment: that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access table contents with `my_table.Variables` or `my_table.my_column_header`. From there, you can compare the values with `A`, `B` and `C`; then create new tables.

```
% Get the ABC column.
content=my_table.Variables;
ABC = char(content{:,2});

% Alternatively, if you have the header.
ABC = char(my_table.Line2);

% Create new tables.
tableA = table(my_table(ABC == 'A',:));
tableB = table(my_table(ABC == 'B',:));
tableC = table(my_table(ABC == 'C',:));
```