# How can I add a main line and main column for my table?

Tags: matlab

My table:

```
'L1'    'B'
'L2'    'B'
'L3'    'A'
'L4'    'C'
'L5'    'B'
'L6'    'C'
'L7'    'C'
'L8'    'A'
```

How I'd like my table to be:

```
      Line1   Line2
Col1 'L1'    'B'
Col2 'L2'    'B'
Col3 'L3'    'A'
Col4 'L4'    'C'
Col5 'L5'    'B'
Col6 'L6'    'C'
Col7 'L7'    'C'
Col8 'L8'    'A'
```

Then how can I find all lines with B as column, would something like b_values = `table( 'B' == table(:,2))`

Expected output:

```
      Line1   Line2
Col1 'L1'    'B'
Col2 'L2'    'B'
Col5 'L5'    'B'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i create many tables of the main one and store them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51462409/how-can-i-create-many-tables-of-the-main-one-and-store-them)

Comment: Do you want to add the headers `Line1` `Line2` and row names `Colx`? If not, the solution to this question is already in one of your earlier questions.

Answer (score 1):

To obtain the table you want you can use the *VariableNames* and *RowNames* properties of Matlab's [table](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html).

```
L = {'L1';'L2';'L3';'L4';'L5';'L6';'L7';'L8'}
Var = {'B';'B';'A';'C';'B';'C';'C';'A'};
%Create table.
T = table(L,Var);

%Add headers.
T.Properties.VariableNames = {'Line1','Line2'};

%Add row names.
T.Properties.RowNames = {'Col1','Col2','Col3','Col4','Col5','Col6','Col7','Col8'};
```

As pointed out by Anthony, to obtain the subtable simply use logical indexing:

```
>>T(strcmp(T.Line2,'B'),:)

        Line1    Line2
        _____    _____

Col1    'L1'     'B'  
Col2    'L2'     'B'  
Col5    'L5'     'B'
```

Comment: plus 1ed for `strcmp` as it is safer than `==` in my demo

Comment: that didn't work on my dataset maybe it's worth mentioning that i read my table using `readtable()` and the file is a .csv what didn't work is getting the part with only B in it this is the output i got empty` 0-by-2 table` the first part regarding the lines and columns worked

Comment: Thanks Anthony. @alberto, can you expand on what didn't work for you? Is it the addition of `VariableNames` and `RowNames` or obtaining the subtable? Can you share the full error message?

Comment: Yes it did , what didn't work is getting the smaller table with values 'B' in Line2, kindly note i'll need the output table in the same forme as the table i gave as input and i'll save it in a variable not just display in the workspace

Comment: After taking another look even the first part didn't work as it removed the first line i had, it seems that matlab interpreted my table wrong and took my previous first line content 'L1'    'B' as the actual table column name and when i added your method it just erased that first line data

Comment: @alberto Right, try reading your table with `readtable('some.csv','ReadVariableNames',false)` to start with.

Comment: great that fixed the first issue but the second of actually getting the smaller table where values are 'B' only persists

Comment: @alberto That's not really an issue, simply use a new variable and assign to it the result of the command `newtable = T(strcmp(T.Line2,'B'),:);` Let me know if that helps.

Comment: lol the issue there isn't with saving it :) i'm just getting a blank table with only Line1 Line2 in it not getting any values but that might be because i on't want to add the lines naming right now so i'll add it your answer to show what my table looks like.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176504/discussion-between-pkpkpk-and-alberto).